# while using jupyter notebook i got CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython, tensorflow-hub, anaconda3

I am running Jupyter notebook, while trying to run below code i got the error. Can anyone please suggest.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import tensorflow_hub as hub
pre_trained_model = "https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/gnews-swivel-20dim/1"
hub_layer = hub.KerasLayer(pre_trained_model, input_shape=[], dtype=tf.string, trainable=True)
```

Error
URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)>

Comment: I got an work around.

import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

Comment: Disabling verification is not a great solution: the TensorFlow models downloaded from tfhub.dev are arbitrary TensorFlow graph pieces and should be thought of as programs. Executing them from an unverified source is risky.
Before .dev was used as a gTLD, developers and frameworks would sometimes use .dev names to help testing code. Could your system have a leftover from those times that interferes with validating the certificate?

Comment: @sujithramanathan, Can you please respond to arnoegw's comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the verification server for your SSL certificate is failing. Try adding the path in the jupyter config file `c.NotebookApp.client_ca = ''`